# Prove that image and kernel of a matrix are invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A subspace $\mathcal{S}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called invariant for an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ if $Av$ lies in $\mathcal{S}$ whenever $v \in \mathcal{S}$.

1. The image and kernel of a matrix are invariant under the matrix.
2. If $A$ and $B$ are commuting matrices, then the kernel of $A$ is invariant under $B$ and the kernel of $B$ is invariant under $A$. Likewise, the image of $A$ is invariant under $B$ and the image of $B$ is invariant under $A$.

How would you start proving these assertions?

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: @vadim123 so far, I have $v \in \mathcal{S}$ and $Av \in \mathcal{S}$ due to invariance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Take $v \in KerA$. Then $A(Bv)=(AB)v=(BA)v=B(Av)=B\vec{0}=\vec{0}$ (here $AB=BA$, since they are commuting; $Av=\vec{0}$, since $v \in KerA$). What does that mean?

Comment: ok, so this is the proof that the kernel of A is invariant under B. So I'll do the same thing for the image

Comment: @Mark: Yes, take $v \in ImB$ (then how can you represent $v$?) and consider $Av$.

Comment: thanks for the awesome hint!

Answer (score 2):

For 1. you may need to just remind yourself of the definitions of image and kernel. Write out an (arbitrary) element in the kernel, see where A sends it, and check if that element is in the kernel. The same for the image.

For 2. you would do a similar thing. If x is in the kernel of B, then is Ax still in the kernel of B? You will use commutativity and an elementary fact about linear transformations.

Comment: could you help me setting up the arbitrary element for the part 1? how would you start it?

Comment: Here is the whole proof, if you feel that the first n lines are not enough to put you in the right direction, read the n+1th line and try to solve it again. (This is a good strategy for reading proofs in general.) I would write: 
Let $x \in \ker A$. Then, by definition, $Ax = 0$. This implies that $A (Ax) = A 0 = 0$. Thus, $Ax \in \ker A$. Therefore, $A \ker A = \{0\} \subseteq \ker A$. Thus, $\ker A$ is invariant under A.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I realized that my basic skills were shaky.